# Grafana simplejson api implementation

Tags: mongodb, grafana, simplejson, grafana-api

I am novice in this area, started to build an api for simple json, using mongo db. The idea is to show mongo collection metrics like min, max, avg records per day, collections updates or inserts on a daily basis in mongo collection. I am not clear how these simple json api response should be generated. Can any point with simple example, how the response and actual mongo collections data correlates to?

Comment: AFAIK MongoDB doesn't come with a native HTTP API so you'll have to implement one, then write a Grafana data source plugin for it.

Comment: Try: https://github.com/JamesOsgood/mongodb-grafana

Comment: I have looked at mongodb-grafana but having npm issues, so tried simple json but I am not clear on how to send the response based on metrics i get from mongo